# How do you fish out certain strings in a string? LUA

Tags: design-patterns, lua

So I want to fish out a string within a string that looks kind of like this:

```
local x = "define x = 2; output('Hello World')"
x:gsub("output%(PATTERN", function(c)
print(c)
end)
```

I basically want to fish out: "output('Hello World')" But I do not understand how patterns work. So if someone could please tell me that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your example is not the best. If you already know the exact string you're looking for, use that string as your pattern.

So let's say you wanted to know if `"output('Hello World')"` is in x it is a s simple as `x:find("output('Hello World')")`

Patterns come in handy if you only know the structure of your text. Let's say you wanted to know the number that was assigned to x.

```
print(x:match("x = (%d+)"))
```

Please refer to the [Lua manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1) if you don't know how to work with patterns.

If there is any particular pattern you don't understand or if you cannot come up with a pattern to match something specific feel free to ask here.

Edit:

There are multiple ways to get the argument to output.

```
print(x:match("output%((%b'')%)"))

print(x:match("output%b()"):match("%b''"))

print(x:match("output%((.+)%)"))
```

and others

Comment: It is Just that I am remaking my llexer for my programing language and I wan't it to be able to be written on the same line so in this case the argument of output being: "Hello World" Is unknow so I want to get everything from "output(" to ")" if that makes sense

Comment: yeah, why don't you ask this in your question then? :)

Comment: I was pretty clear if you read the example? it said: x:gsub("output%(PATTERN")